# iOS : Control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime-error

I'm getting the error at the appdelegate.m file, at the following line of code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
}
```

I haven't had anything within these brackets before, and no changes were made to the app between my last submission and opening it today. Needless to say I'm a bit thrown off.

**EDIT**

After returning `YES` in the initial field described, I received the same error in another section of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   //return cell;
}
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear and despite what you say about not having anything in this method, I don't believe that this is the case if your app ever compiled - You need to return a `BOOL` from this method - the method signature shows this.  You should return `YES` - the default implementation provided by the Xcode templates does this for you.

Answer (score 2):

The method expects a `BOOL` value to be returned. You usually just return `YES`. Most likely your code was changed.

Comment: doing so fixed the initial error, but created another in a different spot. Posted above in OP

Answer (score 0):

You have commented the code for returning the `cell` value.

Your code for cellforRowatindexpath should be like this.

Your code is clearly modified. Without this the app can not run.

Please check about this.

Make necessary changes related to your app.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        return cell;
    }
```